# Ao importar o projeto android esta dando erro no java.lang

Tags: android

Boa tarde, instalei a IDE android studio no linux e abri o projeto que estou fazendo, mas esta dando erro nos arquivos gradle, no Windows estava funcionando sem erro, só foi vir para o linux que começou a dar esses erros... tentei ver na internet e não consegui, alguém poderia me ajudar?

arquivo app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "project.welcomemoney"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
//    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Arquivo NomeProjeto:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Erro ao carregar o gradle:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing
```

Obrigado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A versão do parâmetro buildToolsVersion (25) está diferente das versões configuradas em compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion e nas bibliotecas de suporte nas dependências (24). Tente deixar tudo na mais recente.